# c# Directories Files, process each top folder individually with its respective sub folders and files

Tags: c#, linq, file, directory

I am trying to get each folder , sub folders and files into an object out of a path.

This path will have many top level folder with many sub folders and files.

I need to process each top folder and its sub folders and files separately.

```
example
```

C:\temp\Folder1\SubFolder\SubFiles
C:\temp\Folder2\SubFiles\SubFolders\SubFiles

Need to process Folder1 with its sub directories and enclose it into an object. and same for folder 2.

here is some code , getting access denied because the stream remains open and if I wrap the stream in a using , its closed before I can process the information.

```
   private static IEnumerable<LocalFile> GetLocalFile(string source)
    {
        return Directory.GetDirectories(source)
            .SelectMany(m =>
            {
                return Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(m, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    var relative = x.Substring(source.Length + 1);
                    var localFile = new LocalFile(relative,
                        () =>
                    {
                        return File.OpenRead(x);
                    });
                    return localFile;
                });
            });
    }


    public sealed class LocalFile
{
    private readonly Func<Task<Stream>> openLocal;

    public LocalFile(string relativePath, Func<Stream> openLocal)
    {
        if (openLocal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(openLocal));
        }

        this.RelativePath = relativePath ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(relativePath));
        this.openLocal = () => Task.FromResult(openLocal());
    }

    public LocalFile(string relativePath, Func<Task<Stream>> openLocal)
    {
        this.RelativePath = relativePath ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(relativePath));
        this.openLocal = openLocal ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(openLocal));
    }

    public string RelativePath { get; }




    public Task<Stream> OpenLocal() => this.openLocal();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some more code to illustrate the issue? I don't really understand what you're doing or where you're encountering issues. Also, you might want to choose a more descriptive question title.

Comment: What exactly is `LocalFile`?

Comment: local file is just an object to hold two properties, the relative path of the file and a stream of the file.

Comment: The issue is , I need to process each top folder individually. The function GetLocal() throw an access denied exception and this is because the file stream is still open , if I wrap the file.openread() in a using it throw another exception cannot access a closed stream, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it...

Made a new class

```
public class LocalFolder
{
    public string FolderPath { get; }
    public IEnumerable<LocalFile> FolderFiles { get; }



    public LocalFolder(string folderPath, IEnumerable<LocalFile> files)
    {
        this.FolderPath = folderPath ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(folderPath));
        this.FolderFiles = files ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(files));
    }
}
```

here is the code

```
 private static IEnumerable<LocalFolder> GetFolderFiles(string source)
    {
        var directories = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(source);

        var folderFiles = directories
            .Where(d => !d.Contains("."))
             .Select(m =>
             {
                 var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(m, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
           .Select(f =>
           {
               var relative = f.Substring(source.Length + 1);

               return new LocalFile(relative, () => File.OpenRead(f));
           });
                 return new LocalFolder(m,
                     files);
             });

        var filesinDir = directories
           .Where(d => d.Contains("."))
            .Select(m =>
            {
                var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
          .Select(f =>
          {
              var relative = f.Substring(source.Length + 1);

              return new LocalFile(relative, () => File.OpenRead(f));
          });
                return new LocalFolder(m,
                    files);
            });

        return folderFiles.Concat(filesinDir);
    }
```

I hope this helps someone whom encounters a similar situation.

Thank you